# Generate Color Plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[image]

There is an object on an area with dimension `M*M` unit cells. The coverage rate `C=1/M * Sum(i=1 to M J(i))` where `J(i)=1` when the cell `i` is covered and `0` otherwise. This is a color scale map representing the visit of the cells vs the times of visiting by the object. So, the legend shows that there are cells which have been visited from 0 to 8 times in `N` number of iterations. Can anyone tell me how this color representation can be coded? What and how this can be generated?

Comment: This question is pretty vague. Have you done any research that we can use to get started?

Comment: This isn't x vs y, this would be plotting a `z` at (x,y), where you map `z` to a colour.

Comment: I have explained the question further.Apologize for the incomplete information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`image`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) (or `imagesc`). You need a matrix of X values and Y values, and the corresponding matrix of Z values.

For example:

```
% generate some x,y
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:10,1:10);
% generate some z values: random numbers from 0 to 8
z = randi([0 8],size(x));
% plot
imagesc(x,y,z)
```

How you determine your x, y, z ... well, you'd have to provide more information.

Comment: Thank you for the response.Ii have edited the question wiht further explanations.

Comment: Well now that you've given more information in your question, what have you tried? Your original question on how to generate the plot has been answered, so now you have to work out how to generate the data that you wish to plot. You won't get much help there until you post your current attempt at doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a two dimensional array and read the information in from a file.